# uploading an image api in django return null

Tags: python, django

my models

```
class Slider(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
description = models.TextField()
```

my views

```
class UploadImage(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Slider.objects.all()
   serializer_class = SliderSerializer
   parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

def perform_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        file = request.data["image"]
        title = request.data['description']
    except KeyError:
        raise ParseError('Request has no resource file attached')
    Slider.objects.create(image=file, description=title)
```

serializers

```
class SliderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Slider
    fields = '__all__'
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api/upload', views.UploadImage.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='home')

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

json

[image: API result in postman]

Hello
I Wrote an API for uploading image in Django but unfortunately it didn't work and when I upload an image it return null and I don't know why.
I appreciate if you help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You probably have to use ```request.FILES``` instead of ```request.data``` for images

Comment: unfortunately not working either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to perform a check as to whether a file exists when the post request is made. I'd advise that you do so in the validate method of the serializer. As for the view, change the `perform_create` method to look like the code below:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

perform_create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: it's the result
{
    "image": [
        "This field may not be null."
    ]
}
also i added blank=True and null = True in my models but unfortunately not working yet